# How to get Cassandra cql string given a Apache Spark Dataframe in 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to get a cql string given a Dataframe. I came across this [function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/Schema.scala#L219)

Where I can do something like this

```
TableDef.fromDataFrame(df, "test", "hello", ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED).cql()
```

It looks to me that the library uses first column as Partition Key and does not care about Clustering Key so how do I specify to use particular set of columns of a Dataframe as a PartitionKey and ParticularSet of columns as a Clustering Key ?

Looks like I can create a new TableDef however I have to do the entire mapping by myself and in some cases the necessary functions like ColumnType are not accessible in Java. for Example I tried to create a new ColumnDef like below

```
new ColumnDef("col5", new PartitionKeyColumn(), ColumnType is not accessible in Java)
```

**Objective:** To get a CQL create Statement from a Spark DataFrame.

**Input** My dataframe can have any number of columns with their respective Spark Types. so say I have a Spark Dataframe with 100 columns where my col8, col9 of my dataframe corresponds to cassandra partitionKey columns and my column10 corresponds to cassandra clustering Key column

```
col1| col2| ...|col100
```

Now I want to use spark-cassandra-connector library to give me a CQL create table statement given the info above.

**Desired Output**

```
create table if not exists test.hello (
   col1 bigint, (whatever column1 type is from my dataframe I just picked bigint randomly)
   col2 varchar,
   col3 double,
   ...
   ...
   col100 bigint,
   primary key(col8,col9)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (col10 DESC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because required components (`PartitionKeyColumn` & instances of `ColumnType`) are objects in Scala, you need to use following syntax to access their intances:

```
// imports
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.ColumnDef;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PartitionKeyColumn$;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TextType$;

// actual code
ColumnDef a = new ColumnDef("col5",  
      PartitionKeyColumn$.MODULE$, TextType$.MODULE$);
```

See code for [ColumnRole](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/Schema.scala#L88) & [PrimitiveTypes](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/PrimitiveColumnType.scala#L18) to find full list of names of objects/classes.

**Update after additional requirements**: Code is lengthy, but should work...

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL example").getOrCreate();

Set<String> partitionKeys = new TreeSet<String>() {{
                add("col1");
                add("col2");
        }};
Map<String, Integer> clustereingKeys = new TreeMap<String, Integer>() {{
                put("col8", 0);
                put("col9", 1);
        }};

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("my-test-file.json");
TableDef td = TableDef.fromDataFrame(df, "test", "hello", 
                ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED);

List<ColumnDef> partKeyList = new ArrayList<ColumnDef>();
List<ColumnDef> clusterColumnList = new ArrayList<ColumnDef>();
List<ColumnDef> regColulmnList = new ArrayList<ColumnDef>();

scala.collection.Iterator<ColumnDef> iter = td.allColumns().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ColumnDef col = iter.next();
        String colName = col.columnName();
        if (partitionKeys.contains(colName)) {
                partKeyList.add(new ColumnDef(colName, 
                                PartitionKeyColumn$.MODULE$, col.columnType()));
        } else if (clustereingKeys.containsKey(colName)) {
                int idx = clustereingKeys.get(colName);
                clusterColumnList.add(new ColumnDef(colName, 
                                new ClusteringColumn(idx), col.columnType()));
        } else {
                regColulmnList.add(new ColumnDef(colName, 
                                RegularColumn$.MODULE$, col.columnType()));
        }
}

TableDef newTd = new TableDef(td.keyspaceName(), td.tableName(), 
                (scala.collection.Seq<ColumnDef>) partKeyList,
                (scala.collection.Seq<ColumnDef>) clusterColumnList, 
                (scala.collection.Seq<ColumnDef>) regColulmnList,
                td.indexes(), td.isView());
String cql = newTd.cql();
System.out.println(cql);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! I am not a Scala guy but now it makes sense what you are saying! So should I assume that there is no easy way to get cql string given a dataframe? Because I feel like   TabelDef.fromDataFrame is almost there!!

Comment: I need to look more on it... As I understand you want to reuse existing definition?

Comment: so I have about 100 columns (col1, col2, ...col100 ) in my spark dataframe. Now I want to get a cql create statement out of it..I can do `TableDef.fromDataFrame(df, "test", "hello", ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED).cql()` to get a CQL create statement but the only problem with this is I am not seeing a way to specify say use col8, col9 as a ParitionKey and use col10 as a clusterKey. If I need to create new TableDef then I need to create a `ColDef` for all my 100 columns which is a bit tedious and I would do as my last resort. It would be great help if you can let me know!

Comment: Can you update question with more detail of what you want to achieve at the end? I correctly understand that you want to generate CQL statement from table definition?

Comment: Hi Alex! I just edited my question and added all the details.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thanks a lot for this I almost ended up with similar code but there are two things missing here. 1) There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` in CREATE TABLE  2) Not Sure how to Specify Clustering Order? and Clustering order there can also be two Columns in the Clustering Order

Comment: As I see in the source code of `TableDef`, the `IF NOT EXISTS` and clustering order, aren't supported by this class. I don't see big problem to add this functionality although - maybe in the future releases...

Comment: Is there anyway someone can add that in a branch or something so I can compile from the source? only reason I ask is I am not a scala guy else I would fork and add it myself.

Comment: I can try to make It, but only my evening

Comment: That would be awesome..so the above code can also be simplified..Whatever you can..It would be a great help!!

Comment: See the https://github.com/alexott/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/tabledef-improvements branch - it has all changes. the `TableDef` constructor has last argument that allows to specify that you need `IF NOT EXISTS`.  And ClusteringColumn constructor now takes 2nd argument that specify sorting - true -> ASC, false -> DESC

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex!! I integrated your commit however I get the following error. ```java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.ColumnDef cannot be cast to com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.ClusteringColumn
com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$14.apply(Schema.scala:200)
com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$$anonfun$14.apply(Schema.scala:199)```

Comment: Works like a charm!!